# Progress OpenEdge how to prevent someone from updating a record

Tags: updating, progress-4gl, openedge

I need an alternative way to prevent someone from accessing a particular piece of code.

I'll explain the scenario.

There are two programs.

In the first program an end-user creates a proforma invoice. When he/she then views the details on the invoice. The code displays the details with the main table's record in EXCLUSIVE-LOCK. This is to prevent other end-users from changing anything while the first user is busy viewing the details. So even when the proforma invoice is completed and can no longer be changed. The main table's record is still in EXCLUSIVE-LOCK. which is wrong, but it prevents other users from messing with it while the first user is still busy updating it. However, the people who work in this program leave the program in the detail view. They don't go out.

The problem is when the second program is used to dispatch the items on the proforma invoice. It uses the same main table's record. And therefore can't do anything because the first program still has it in EXCLUSIVE-LOCK.

My question is...

How can I prevent users changing data in the first program as if the main table's record was in EXCLUSIVE-LOCK, but without actually having it in exclusive-lock? Over multiple sessions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be better a comment, but I don't have enough reputation points to make comments. Sorry.

Some notes:

1. Optimistic locking -- if it is viable for your situation -- is almost certainly the best solution.
2. If you are going to add an isLocked field to the table, you will probably want several other fields:

   - Date/Time the record was locked -- or else an expiration timestamp
   - LockHolder -- so you know whether or not you've got it.
3. The expiration can be automatic (as with a cron sweep), or can be ignored unless someone else wants the record.  The program which sets the lock must also be smart enough to check to see if it still holds it.  It gets complicated.
4. There are times when it is not convenient to make schema changes to a table, or there are too many tables that need changes.  In those cases, you can add these fields to a separate LockIt table.  One table can handle these locks for all your other tables.

Aside:
We also use our LockIt table for another purpose:  to make sure that only one copy of a given program can run at a time.  (Usually this is for cron jobs or a batch daemon.)  The program exclusive-locks a particular record in the LockIt table (but DOES NOT start a transaction!), and it holds that lock as long as the program is running.

Comment: Love it. Unfortunately I tried this and the solution above with my boss. He said no to both. I did learn from this anyway so thanks everyone.

Comment: So, what are your boss's requirements?  Here's another possibility:  Add an auto-timeout to the program that is keeping the record locked.  If there is no activity for (say) 30 minutes; it can back out.  If you really want to get fancy, it could even save any changes that were made -- either to the table itself, or to a separate tracking table.  If there is a problem, there is probably a solution; the hard part is sometimes asking the right question.

Comment: He wants it to stay as is. After all that I just had to make sure that everything in program that got blocked is undone upon pressing ctrl-c. That I did.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your transaction scope is wrong. I'll go ahead and assume you are trying to dispatch with the invoicing program still open. Then you can't, because the record is still locked. Chances are your whole program is a transaction, and the record will keep locked for as long as the screen is running. Try and revisit your updates, enclose your real update operations in a DO TRANSACTION block, put some MESSAGE TRANSACTION statements around in different places and see what the results are. This will help you find the points in which Progress is being led to "believe" the record still needs to be locked.

Comment: You're quite right. I found the places in the program already. At those points records are only being read. No need for exclusive-lock. The program as it is intentionally reads the records with exclusive lock just to keep other end-users from getting in.------------- FIND FIRST "table" WHERE "blablabla" EXLCUSIVE-LOCK NO-WAIT NO-ERROR ==== > IF LOCK "table" THEN RETURN NO-APPLY............ That's all it serves. So I need to find a way to block the other end-users from reading/updating without blocking dispatch in the process.

Comment: In the company I'm currently working for, we use AppServer, so if you know how those work, you know we can't hold locks. What we do, then, is have a field stating that record is locked. So other users can't change the order when it's being invoiced or dispatched, like you are mentioning. A char or boolean field will do, if you have the ok to change schema. If you don't, which is actually the easiest solution, you'll have to scope your lock holds specifically to the points when the user is issuing or modifying an invoice record.

Comment: That's the same solution I had in mind. First wanted to make sure that there wasn't something in Progress that existed for this sort of thing. Thanks bupereira...

Answer (score -1):

I assume you're not using appserver since this behaviour most likely wouldn't be a problem in that case.

One solution could be to change into a "optimistic locking" approach. This means that you start out with a "NO-LOCK" and once you need to change the record you upgrade the lock to EXCLUSIVE-LOCK. This approach will work but you will need to make sure that the record still exists and isn't changed by some other user.

Depending on how often your invoices actually change this might (or might not) be a solution. If a mishap happens "once in a while" this might be a viable solution. If it happens often (every day or so) you need to do something else.

Basic pseudo code for an optimistic approach:

```
FIND FIRST record WHERE somethingsomething NO-LOCK.

/* Here goes code for displaying the record */
/* .... */

/* Here's the updates */
IF userWantsToSave THEN DO:
    FIND CURRENT record EXCLUSIVE-LOCK NO-ERROR NO-WAIT.
    IF AVAILABLE record THEN DO:
        IF CURRENT-CHANGED record THEN DO:
            MESSAGE "Changed!" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX ERROR.
            /* Your code goes here */
        END.
        ELSE DO:
            /* Your code for updating goes here */

            MESSAGE "Success!" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFORMATION.
        END.
    END.    
    ELSE IF NOT AVAILABLE record THEN DO:
        IF LOCKED record THEN DO:
            MESSAGE "Locked!" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX ERROR.
            /* Your code goes here */
        END.
        ELSE DO:
            MESSAGE "Deleted!" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX ERROR.
            /* Your code goes here */
        END.
    END. 
END.
```

[Here's an example from the knowledgebase that goes more into depth with this.](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/21500)

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'm very fond of the optimistic approach. This specific problem however, at the point where we test for exclusive-lock, the record should not be in "EXCLUSIVE-LOCK" at all. There is no updating/adding/deleting. It sole purpose is to block the other end-users using the same program for the same proforma invoice. The problem at hand, is that it blocks everyone else that uses the same record in other programs, where they should be able to access it.. Dispatch should be able to dispatch while other people can't mess around with the invoice while someone is busy with it.